# Extending ssl sharepoint site with extranet

Tags: sharepoint, iis, ssl, sharepoint-2007, forms-authentication

So I have this project I took over from another guy - whom I can't consult with unfortunately. And I have no experience in SSL.

Basically there's this sharepoint web-app which has been setup to use SSL - and everything's working great. I see in the central admin page, that there are two zones to the web-app (standard and internet). In IIS there are 2 web sites containing to this sharepoint site.

One has the port value TCP 0 and SSL port 443, the other a TCP 80 with a redirect to the SSL website. So far so good.

Now I need to extend this website with a forms-authenticated extranet. How do I go about this?

I did, what I would do with a normal sharepoint website, and first extended the web-app from central admin, remembered to set the zone to extranet, and checked "use SSL". (port 1580)

I went into the web-config file in the virtual directory, and set up the forms-stuff (connection string, providers, etc.).

But then I was stumped as to how to actually access this extranet. I couldn't access it by doing:

```
http://site.com:1580
or
https://site.com:1580
```

And I tried just changing the existing redirect to the virtual directory of the extranet - no dice. I know this is simple, so there must be someone who can explain it to me, as if I was a child :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that IIS does not know about your 1580 port.

Go into IIS manager, into the new extended web site, and check that the 1580 port has been mapped to it. Check that the SSL port has been mapped too. And don't forget to add the certificate.

Comment: It was the certificate that wasn't properly assigned  - Thanks!